# updates.jenkins.io: Temporary failure in name resolution while building jenkins docker image in docker in docker Jenkins agent running on K8S

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, docker-build, docker-in-docker

I'm using dynamically provisioned docker in docker agent as Kubernetes pod in [Jenkins helm chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins).

Docker in Docker agent uses 2 images, one with `docker` client, one with `docker` daemon. Their `Dockerfile` is below:

- `dind-client`

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-agent-docker
USER root

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

USER jenkins
ENTRYPOINT "/entrypoint.sh"
```

- `entrypoint.sh` busy waits for `docker-daemon` to become available:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RETRIES=6

sleep_exp_backoff=1

for((i=0;i<RETRIES;i++)); do
    docker version
    dockerd_available=$?
    if [ $dockerd_available == 0 ]; then
        break 
    fi
    sleep ${sleep_exp_backoff}
    sleep_exp_backoff="$((sleep_exp_backoff * 2))"
done

exec /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent "$@"
```

- `dind-daemon`

`FROM docker:20.10.14-dind`

- `docker-agent` is configured to run in Jenkins helm chart using below values in  `values.yaml`:

```
dind:
    podName: docker-agent
    customJenkinsLabels: docker-agent
    image: [url]/docker-client
    tag: latest
    envVars:
     - name: DOCKER_HOST
       value: "tcp://localhost:2375"
    alwaysPullImage: true
    yamlTemplate:  |-  
     spec: 
         containers:
           - name: dind-daemon 
             image: [url]/docker-daemon:latest
             securityContext: 
               privileged: true
             env: 
               - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
                 value: ""
```

- I'm trying to build below image using the agent:

```
FROM docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

# Add Jenkins init files
COPY src/ /usr/share/jenkins/ref/

COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --verbose --plugin-file /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

USER jenkins
```

- Below error pops during `RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --verbose --plugin-file /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt` stage of `docker build` command inside the agent during jenkin build using the agent.

```
12:39:03  Retrieving update center information
12:39:03  Created cache at: /var/jenkins_home/.cache/jenkins-plugin-management-cli
12:39:03  Update center URL: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?version=2.346.1
12:39:03  Cache miss for: update-center-2.346.1
12:39:03  Unable to retrieve JSON from https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?version=2.346.1: updates.jenkins.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
12:39:03  Unable to retrieve JSON from https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?version=2.346.1: updates.jenkins.io
12:39:03  io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.UpdateCenterInfoRetrievalException: Error getting update center json
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.getJson(PluginManager.java:810)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.getUCJson(PluginManager.java:832)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:217)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:181)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:70)
12:39:03  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to retrieve JSON from https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?version=2.346.1: updates.jenkins.io
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.getViaHttpWithResponseHandler(PluginManager.java:1344)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.getJson(PluginManager.java:796)
12:39:03    ... 4 more
12:39:03  Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io
12:39:03    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801)
12:39:03    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
12:39:03    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367)
12:39:03    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221)
12:39:03    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
12:39:03    at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.impl.PluginManager.getViaHttpWithResponseHandler(PluginManager.java:1336)
12:39:03    ... 5 more
12:39:03  Error getting update center json
12:39:05  The command '/bin/sh -c jenkins-plugin-cli --verbose --plugin-file /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

- Jenkins pipeline runs `docker build` in `sh` step:

`rc = sh(returnStatus: true, script: "docker build -t ${REGISTRY}/${REPO_NAME}/${NAME} .")`

- It seems like the issue is dns issue. More specifically, failure to resolve `updates.jenkins.io` inside intermediate container which is running during specific `docker build` stage in `docker-daemon` container

So I ran the image in the same `k8s` cluster and tried to resolve `updates.jenkins.io` locally inside the container, it worked:

```
kubectl run --image=[...]  --privileged=true dind
kubectl exec -it pod/dind sh
/ # nslookup updates.jenkins.io
...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   updates.jenkins.io
Address: 52.202.51.185
...
```

- I then tried to replicate the failing use case (container running inside `docker-daemon` container and `updates.jenkins.io` not resolving inside it) and the resolution worked:

```
kubectl run --image=[...]  --privileged=true dind
kubectl exec -it pod/dind sh
docker run -it alpine sh
/ # nslookup updates.jenkins.io
...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   updates.jenkins.io
Address: 52.202.51.185
...
```

Not sure why then the dns issue pops during `docker build`.

Comment: This is one of the issues I faced in the past; try adding --mtu=1440 in the dind container args field.